Loosely-coupled database structure, interface for entities
Preliminaries: I am creating an application using .NET Core and EF Core.
Here is the problem: consider two entities called Form1 and Car, like this:
public class Form1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Form1Car> FormCars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Form1Car> Form1Cars { get; set; }
}

Therefore the straightforward answer is as follows:
public class Form1Car
{
    public int Form1Id { get; set; }
    public Form Form1 { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

However, in the future if I wanted to add more form then the structure become distorted. Let this entity be Form2, but then the table for Car should be updated into
public class Form2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Form2Car> FormCars { get; set; }
}

public class Form1Car
{
    public int Form2Id { get; set; }
    public Form Form2 { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Form1Car> Form1Cars { get; set; }
    public List<Form2Car> Form2Cars { get; set; }
}

I thought that this solution is the opposite of best practice. But then I thought creating interface for the whole Form entity, then it has the form
public interface IForm
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
}

public class Form1 : IForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
}

public class Form2 : IForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CarForm> CarForms { get; set; }
}

public class CarForm
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public IForm Form { get; set; }
    public string FormType { get; set; }
}

Is it really best practice? I am really need of help. Thanks in advance!

Are you looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance?

Is FormNCar  a sort of many-to-many relation between FormN and Car?

@Dennis yes of course.

@Progman I don't think that it is helpful

Basically, the problem is in the approach which is imposed by most of EF tutorials.
Just remember: you don't need to put every navigation property in every related entity type.
According to model in your post, Car should forget about "forms", since it isn't a necessity for the Car itself:
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

The same is true for forms, e.g.:
public class FormN
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

The only type, which must be aware of Car and FormN is a many-to-many relation type:
public class FormNCar
{
    public int FormNId { get; set; }
    public Form FormN { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

When you need cars having FormN forms, or forms having particular Cars, build a query to Set<FormNCar>.
I don't know anything about your "forms" in actual domain model, but if inheritance is applicable, you can inherit forms and/or many-to-many relation types.
My advice is to avoid extra navigation properties until they really needed.
